# Google maps marker no puede ser colocado

Tags: google-maps

he estado tratando de agregar en google maps un punto de interes pero lo mas a lo que he llegado es que solo es visible para mi. existe algun proceso para dar de lata un punto de interes en google maps y que sea definitivo para todo mundo. gracias por compartir.

Comment: Hola, agregar el código para que podamos entender tu problema, también puedes incluir capturas de tu mapa.

Comment: Suele tardar unos días en aparecer, debe pasar a revisión y que lo aprueben, si has hecho bien el proceso, de lo cual no dices nada en tu pregunta.